# How do I pickle and unpickle a list of objects in python?

Tags: list, object, pickle

I'm working on a program in Python that has objects (Stars and Planets), which I'm trying to save at the end of each run of code and load at the beginning. I'm appending the objects to a list (starlist for stars, planetlist for planets) when they are created, and the lists are pickled in my save function, then unpickled in my load function. But when they are unpickled, the lists are empty.

I'm trying to pickle and unpickle lists of objects, and then access the objects in that list. The lists are empty after unpickling, however.

These are my save functions:

```
def SaveStars():
    with open('StarData.pkl', 'wb') as savefile:
        pickle.dump(starlist, savefile)
        savefile.close()
        
def SavePlanets():
   with open('PlanetData.pkl', 'wb') as savefile:
        pickle.dump(planetlist, savefile)
        savefile.close()
```

And these are my loading functions:

```
def LoadStars():
    with open('StarData.pkl', 'rb') as loadfile:
        starlist = pickle.load(loadfile)
        loadfile.close()

def LoadPlanets():
    with open('PlanetData.pkl', 'rb') as loadfile:
        planetlist = pickle.load(loadfile)
        loadfile.close()
```